# Listing files with date command and return word count

Tags: scripting

I want to create a script which can list files in particular directory and return the count.

For example i have file name:

```
abc_20121018.txt
bcddelhi_20121017.txt
zxy_20121018
```

i want to list only files which has `20121018` in it with the date command.

Comment: Need more details. What scripting language? (bash, perl, ruby, cmd, etc.) What OS? What have you tried already?

Answer (score 0):

i dont understand why you need  a date command to do this if you just want to get the files with 20121018 in it!

use the below command:

```
ls -1 *_20121018.txt|wc -l
```

Comment: i want to create the script so that i don't want to do this manually because every day 7-8 files come to my server with previous day, so buy running command manually run a script and it gives filename and count.